# What is a more efficient way of tallying up random numbers and printing them?

Tags: python

So... the code does what I want it to do. Although, as far as I know, it seems very inefficient and I've been told it is. Essentially, I am rolling 2 dices and so it would range up from 2 to 12 (added up respectively). Then I would tally up whether if it rolls to add up 2, 3, 4, and so on. Seeing the way I did it, I made 11 variables and 11 if and elif statements which is extremely redundant and seems to be inefficient.

I do not know how to make it more efficient or if there is a more pythonic way of doing it.

```
def distribution_of_rolls(amount: int) -> str:
    count2 = ''
    count3 = ''
    count4 = ''
    count5 = ''
    count6 = ''
    count7 = ''
    count8 = ''
    count9 = ''
    count10 = ''
    count11 = ''
    count12 = ''
        countList = [count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9, count10, count11, count12
]
resultStr = ''
for _ in range(amount):
    roll = roll2dice()
    if roll == 2:
        countList[0] += '*'
    elif roll == 3:
        countList[1] += '*'
    elif roll == 4:
        countList[2] += '*'
    elif roll == 5:
        countList[3] += '*'
    elif roll == 6:
        countList[4] += '*'
    elif roll == 7:
        countList[5] += '*'
    elif roll == 8:
        countList[6] += '*'
    elif roll == 9:
        countList[7] += '*'
    elif roll == 10:
        countList[8] += '*'
    elif roll == 11:
        countList[9] += '*'
    elif roll == 12:
        countList[10] += '*'

    for i in range(2, 13):
        resultStr += (str(i) + ':    ' + str(len(countList[i - 2])) + ' ' + countList[i - 2] + "\n")

    print(resultStr)
    distribution_of_rolls(200)
```

Here is the result (No issues, it's what I wanted):

```
2:    3 ***
3:    11 ***********
4:    17 *****************
5:    18 ******************
6:    22 **********************
7:    37 *************************************
8:    32 ********************************
9:    23 ***********************
10:    15 ***************
11:    14 **************
12:    8 ********
```

Comment: drop all if/else, use indexes: `countList[roll-2] += '*'`

Comment: also use lists / `collections.Counter` and string multiply to avoid string concatenation. Maybe good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should always divide data and representation. Count as integers, but later present as `*`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review question

Comment: Hmm. If I drop all the if/else how will it know how to tally according to what the roll amounts to?

Also, I did not know code review was a thing. Thanks for the info

Comment: What's unclear about Jean-Francois's suggestion? It would do exactly what it's doing now, but neater. There are no side effects unless you pass invalid information.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what collections counter did. But now I see. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter` to make it more efficient

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(roll2dice() for _ in range(200))
>>> for i in range(2,14):
        print (f'{i:2}:  {c[i]:2} {"*"*c[i]}')
... 
 2:  12 ************
 3:  20 ********************
 4:  13 *************
 5:  19 *******************
 6:  13 *************
 7:  20 ********************
 8:   9 *********
 9:  18 ******************
10:  15 ***************
11:  19 *******************
12:  22 **********************
13:  20 ********************
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know there was such thing. I will study up on collections.Counter. Thanks again